# Read A Large File Using Java NIO

Tags: java, nio, large-files

I need to read the content of a large file. For that I Googled on it and found so many methods and resources. But I'm still confused which is the method to read the large files (Factors need to be consider in my case are memory allocation, performance, large file )

1. Using `FileChannel`
2. using `Files.readAllLines`
3. using `BufferedReader`

Can anyone guide on this?

Comment: And what do you do with the contents? Also, since you mention `.readAllLines()`, I take it the contents are text?

Comment: @DavidG I actually did not add add these lines. There's something wrong here ... I removed the caps from the title and modified the list (also changed so "i" to "I" but that's all

Comment: @DavidG He didn't add that. He just didn't refresh his edit after someone else made an edit before him. I don't know if he just ignored the message about that fact during his edit.

Comment: @DavidG I know I just checked but I did not add these lines, I'm sure of it. Tom, yup I guess that's the issue. Sorry

Comment: @LBesancon Yes, I see another user trying to add it again, sorry for accusing you! :)

Comment: @AkshayArora Do NOT add "thanks" messages to questions, that content is not useful.

Comment: @DavidG no problem ;)

Comment: @fge Here contents means what is on the file. Which means I need to read the particular file and then I need to print on terminal.

Comment: @DavidG This happens because they start editing where that "thanks" is still there. Then someone removes that during their edit and they ignore the info message that the post was already edited. So that edit by the other user will then be "rolled back".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is to read the file lazily. Fetch each line one at a time and process.

Example:-

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:/files", "yourfile.txt"));
```

Then process the lines afterwords.

From the [official](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) documentation:-

```
public static Stream<String> lines(Path path, Charset cs) throws IOException
```

> Read all lines from a file as a Stream. Unlike readAllLines, this
>   method does not read all lines into a List, but instead populates
>   lazily as the stream is consumed.

Comment: Is this good for performance vice? May I use this in any case

Comment: @KALYANIYOGESWARANATHAN Yes, since the processing happens one line at a time (lazily) it wont be an issue with performance

Comment: @KALYANIYOGESWARANATHAN Please accept the answer if you find what you are looking for.